# how does JFrame refresh itself?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, copy

this is my code

```
public class ComboBoxDemo extends JFrame {
ArrayList<Common.DescriptionPanel> cartoon = new ArrayList<Common.DescriptionPanel>();
ArrayList<ImageIcon> image = new ArrayList<ImageIcon>();
ArrayList<String> title = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> description = new ArrayList<String>();
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();

Common.DescriptionPanel panel = new Common.DescriptionPanel();


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Common.SetFrame(new ComboBoxDemo(), "Combo Box");
}


public ComboBoxDemo() {
    addCartoon(new ImageIcon("c.jpg"), "Mario", "This is Mario");
    addCartoon(new ImageIcon("d.jpg"), "Sonic", "This is Sonic");
    addCartoon(new ImageIcon("e.jpg"), "Astro Boy", "This is Astro Boy");

    for (int i = 0; i < cartoon.size(); i++) {
        cartoon.get(i).setImage(image.get(i));
        cartoon.get(i).setTitle(title.get(i));
        cartoon.get(i).setDescription(description.get(i));
        combo.addItem(title.get(i));
    }

    combo.setBackground(Color.white);
    combo.setForeground(Color.blue);
    combo.setSelectedItem(cartoon.get(0));

    panel = cartoon.get(0);

    add(combo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            panel = cartoon.get(combo.getSelectedIndex());

            pack();
            System.out.println(panel.textArea.getText());
        }
    });
}

void addCartoon(ImageIcon image, String title, String description) {
    cartoon.add(new Common.DescriptionPanel());
    this.image.add(image);
    this.title.add(title);
    this.description.add(description);

}
```

}

and the code of DescriptionPanel is

public class DescriptionPanel extends JPanel {

```
private JLabel imageTitle = new JLabel();
public JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

public DescriptionPanel() {
    imageTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    imageTitle.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
    imageTitle.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
    imageTitle.setFont(Common.SetFont.boldFont);


    textArea.setLineWrap(true);   //when one line doesn't fit, it will jump to next line automatically
    /*
     * The wrapStyleWord property is set to true (line 23) so that the line is wrapped 
     * on words rather than characters. 
     */
    textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setFont(Common.SetFont.boldFont);
    textArea.setForeground(Color.blue);

    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2)); 

    add(imageTitle);
    add(scrollpane);


}

public void setImage(ImageIcon image) {
    imageTitle.setIcon(image);
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    imageTitle.setText(title);
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    textArea.setText(description);
}
```

}

when I reselect the combobox, JFrame won't change at all,
so i replace the code

```
                panel = cartoon.get(combo.getSelectedIndex());
```

to the code

```
panel.setTitle(title.get(combo.getSelectedIndex()));
            panel.setDescription(description.get(combo.getSelectedIndex()));
            panel.setImage(image.get(combo.getSelectedIndex()));
```

and it works.

so what is the difference of these two code?
In the first code, the panel apparently change, because when I print the textarea out, it is different from the initial panel, but JFrame doesn't change.

why the second code can work?

Comment: The difference between those two codes? 100% - there is nothing the same about them. One sets `panel` to something, the other sets properties on `panel` to values.

Comment: You should NEVER maintain components within `JComboBox` (or `JList`, or `JTree` or `JTable`).  These components should provide basic data, which each component can then be configured separately to display differently as required.  Once selected, you should simply modify the properties of what ever component you are using to display the data maintained by the `JComboBox` (which your second example basically does)

Comment: `panel = cartoon.get(combo.getSelectedIndex());` - please explain in your own words what you think this does.

Comment: @immibis I copy the "cartoon.get(combo.getSelectedIndex())" panel to "panel" object, so I think since the reference of "panel" already change, so JFrame will refresh

Comment: `cartoon.get(combo.getSelectedIndex())` returns a reference to a panel which is not visible, so after that statement `panel` contains a reference to the same panel (which is still not visible, because nothing made it visible). That doesn't really accomplish anything useful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
panel = cartoon.get(combo.getSelectedIndex());
```

This simply changes the reference of `panel` (what it's pointing to in memory) to what ever is stored within the current combobox position.  It does not effect what `panel` was once referencing.

```
panel.setTitle(title.get(combo.getSelectedIndex()));
panel.setDescription(description.get(combo.getSelectedIndex()));
panel.setImage(image.get(combo.getSelectedIndex()));
```

Changes the properties of the current object that the variable `panel` is referencing.

Because you have previous added `panel` to the frame (`add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);`, it will effect the component that is on the screen.

You should NEVER maintain component based data within this type of component.  Instead, your combobox should be filled with data, which it can use to renderer a desired result, based on the current needs of the UI and which you can use to effect some other view.  This is the basic concept of the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) paradigm.

Comment: frame only display the old reference even panel's reference already change? So what I should to is to change the properties comes from old reference?         suppose I already assign panel with new reference, does it mean the properties from old reference can not be change??

Comment: Essentially, yes. If you change the reference, then what you change is not what you use to pint to, but what you are now pointing to

Comment: What you should do, is separate you data from the view.  Then allow the view to take a copy of the data and update itself accordingly, this way, you never change the reference of the view, but simply give it new data to display